# Migrate posts from category and sub-category via SQL

Tags: posts, wp-query, categories, sql

I am trying to migrate all contents from a category to another using SQL. 
Thanks for help.

[image]

I want to change the term_taxonomy_id of this query.

Comment: What's the reasoning behind doing it in SQL? Would it not be faster to just rename 2018 to 2017 instead of moving each post? Then you'd only have to create 1 term for the latest year and one for the oldest year

Comment: Also, is there a particular reason this isn't being done via WP CLI?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @TomJNowell , the reason is that i have many posts from 2008 to today. I want to create a script to archive each of these posts to the corresponding year.

Comment: My query give me a line, for example. How can i change corresponding attributs of this line which is the result of my query "SELECT * ..." ?

Comment: So to be clear ( i'm still unsure exactly what you're planning to do ), you have categories: 2008,2009,2010, etc. You want to take the posts in the `2010` term and move them to the `2009` term, and do the same for every other year? Then delete the posts that were in the oldest year? Can you edit your question to be clearer and not reference SQL when explaining what you're trying to do? As well as some context. Some of the things you mentioned don't make much sense e.g. "decrement the content of a category to another category"

Comment: I have edited my post, maybe it's better for the comprehension now.

Comment: That doesn't help understand what you're doing, just that you've come up with an SQL query that doesn't do what you want, but you didn't clearly explain what you want, just that your solution to the problem is broken. We still don't know what you're trying to achieve, so any talk of SQL is just confusing

Comment: I am trying to move all the contents of a category to another, can't be more explicit ? But i want to do this via SQL and not via the back office of wordpress.

Comment: That's the first time you've explicitly stated it, all this talk of SQL and categories with years and decrementing etc is confusing. Can you remove that from your question and simplify it so it's closer to the problem? Additionally, why use SQL? This can be done entirely via other means

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93151/discussion-between-tweak-and-tom-j-nowell).

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect the reason you want SQL that you haven't mentioned/shared, is because you can't use the WP functions to fetch the posts and do it manually in a single request due to the PHP time execution limit, or you don't know how to.

Sadly, doing it via SQL is no guarantee this will work, additionally, you'll break all the caches involved, all the term post counts will be broken, and a few other things too.

The best way to do this, is with WP CLI, for example here we take all posts in category X, put them in category Y, then remove them from X:

```sh
# get all the post IDs in category x
posts=wp post list --category_name="x" --field="ID"

# Move them from x to Y
for id in $posts
do
  wp post term remove $id cat "x" --by="slug"
  wp post term add $id cat "y" --by="slug"
done
```

But given you've hinted you're actually doing this by year, it might be easier to simply rename the terms, so `2010` -> `2009`, `2011` -> `2010` etc. This would be much much faster/reliable/simpler.